# I can not run any query on BigQuery in region europe-west2 anymore (transient error n°4233314)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I can no longer query nor preview any table nor run any job in my BigQuery (region europe-west2). When I run a query in an other region, I don't get the error so it's specific to my region.
When trying to run any query, I get the following error in the GCP Console:

> An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.
> This is usually caused by a transient issue. Retrying the job with
> back-off as described in the BigQuery SLA should solve the problem:
> https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla. If the error continues to occur
> please contact support at https://cloud.google.com/support. Error:
> 4233314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm that the europe-west2 Google Cloud services like App Engine or Firestore are down...